# What beracha do you make on Golden Puffs?

Tags: halacha, blessing, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern

Golden Puffs is a honey glazed puffed wheat cereal.
I'm looking for the sephardic minhag.
Preferably an answer from Rabbi Ovadia Yosef.
I've narrowed it down to either adamah or mezonot.

Comment: In Rav Marlow's Berochos guide, which is based on the Shulchan Aruch Harav, he says that it's Ha'adama and borei nefashos, but it's preferable to eat it in a meal. I assume making a mezonos and ha'adama on two things that definitely have those berochos would be the same thing as having it in a meal. As for whether sefardim make mezonos or ha'adama, i don't know, but if you want to be machmir, then have it in a meal.

Answer (score 2):

The Shulchan Aruch O.C. 208:4 writes:

> אכל דגן חי או עשוי קליות או שלוק והגרעינין שלמים אינו מברך אלא בורא פרי האדמה ולאחריו בורא נפשות.
>
> והתוספות נסתפקו אם יברך לאחריו ברכה מעין שלש ולכך כתבו שנכון שלא לאכלו אלא בתוך הסעודה ויפטרנו ברכת המזון
>
> If you eat raw or roasted wheat ... and it is whole, the blessing is Ha'adama and Borei Nefashos.  However, Tosefos entertained the possibility that it should get a Me'ein Shalosh (Al Hamichya) and therefore wrote not to eat it except in the middle of a meal, in which case it is covered by Birkas Hamazon.

Puffed wheat [is made](http://www.ehow.com/how_8658559_puff-wheat.html) by roasting the wheat kernels in a popper.

Generally Sephardi custom follows the opinion of the Shulchan Aruch. Therefore, I would assume the blessing is Adama and Borei Nefashos, and if you want to be extra-careful, eat it in a meal.